# Dynamic FormType creaton and serialization

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically create forms in Symfony from GUI. I'd like to build a GUI for form creation, so I could inject form to some templates from GUI and not hard code it.

I would create hooks in template to dynamically add forms.

There are similar things in WP and Drupal already.

I hope I've verbalized what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

That's a "CMSey" feature but Symfony is a framework/middleware so you don't get that OOTB.

There *are* some CMSes built on Symfony, though, so maybe you want to start there?

- http://www.pagekit.com/
- http://redkite-labs.com/

And there very-well may be a bundle out there that does what you're looking for but I don't know of one off the top of my head.

Comment: I know what are you referring to. But, I just want to make dynamic settings form for my backend, not CMSlike website.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go with this. Can you build symfony forms dynamically? Yes. Can you build them based on information in a data-store such as a database? Yes. Can you build a GUI that let's you configure that data-store? Yes.  You have all the parts you need, so just go make it!